# How do I allow mstsc to auto-populate my credentials?

Tags: windows-server-2003, remote-desktop, mstsc

mstsc allows you to save your credentials for a system so you don't have to type them in every times, which is nice when you use randomly-generated long passwords.

My Server 2008 machine allows this just fine, but on my Server 2003 system it fails, with the message:

```
The system could not log you on. Make sure your User name and domain are correct, then type your password again.
```

I'm positive the credentials I'm saving are correct, and when I type it in by hand it works.

Comment: Are you entering the Domain as well, or just your username and password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try saving RDP files using MSTSC. There may be a bug with caching them and selecting the servers from the drop-down menu.

How about looking here? [Microsoft](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb457145.aspx)

Comment: Nope, saving an RDP file didn't make a difference. Another 2003 server allows this, so it must be a setting.

Comment: Edited answer. Take a look.